# Am I missing a step with phonegap facebook plugin?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I cloned the entire https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin repo into my phonegap project (not sure that was necessary), and then I added the cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js, facebook-js-sdk.js, and the plugin.xml file into my www directory.

It's not finding the CDV or FB variable. It's telling me to make sure the above files were added correctly.

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

According to your explanation, you are missing a few steps if installing it manually. Moreover, it is not rquired to clone the plugin repo directly within your project.

Setting the Phonegap Facebook plugin used to be quite  long process. Now it is a little easier thanks to CLI tools and automatic installation.

Both automatic and manual installation procedures are described in detail here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/README.md

I would reccomend carefully going through it in order to success.

Best.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please help with the CLI commands? I don't understand the "/Users/your/path/here/" part. I assume the path should add the plugin into the www folder but it doesn't work. It says "Error: Failed to fetch package information for angularApp/www/phonegap-facebook-plugin". 

The command line definitely seems like it should make it an easy process but I can't figure out the correct path.

Comment: The specific command requires the path to the plugin repo. Something like this: "cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID=yourFacebookAppId --variable APP_NAME=yourAppName" The plugin will be installed under the plugins folder. Hope it helps!

Comment: I got Error: Failed to fetch package information for github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: I added https:// and the entire repo was added to my directory via git-clone, which brings me back to my original question: Are there any additional steps I need to take aside from moving the plugin files into my www directory?

Comment: I just did it by myself and got it properly installed under the plugins folder. You should find a folder like this: ls ./plugins/
-> com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect, and the install command shoul echo something like this: [phonegap] adding the plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
[phonegap] successfully added the plugin. Is it the case for you?

Comment: My original attempt was actually pretty close to correct. I moved the cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js, facebook-js-sdk.js, and plugin.xml file into my www directory. The problem I was having before was that my script tags with the facebook functions came before the script tags that required the above files. Once I put those before the facebook functions it worked properly.

Comment: Nice to hear you solved it! However, I would recommend using the CLI tools for adding plugins since they make all this file movements and script tag additions for you. So those steps become transparent to the developer.

Comment: It seems to be calling facebook correctly but I'm having a lot of problems getting it to work. I keep getting the error "Given URL is not allowed by the application configuration...", but I have included the correct local host URL in my facebook app dashboard. Do you have experience getting the plugin to work properly? I really need some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/Users/your/path/here/"
```

It is the path of folder which you extract from "phonegap-facebook-plugin-master.zip" (downloaded from github as zip) i.e. "C:\Users\XXX\phonegap-facebook-plugin-master" >>>Windows<<<